# Command Line Pipe Input in Java

Tags: java, file, command-line, input, pipe

Here is a simple piece of code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Read {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  while(true)
  {
   String x = null;
   try{
    x = f.readLine();
   }
   catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
   System.out.println(x);
  }
 }
}
```

I execute this as :    java Read < input.txt

Once the input.txt is completely piped into the program, x keeps getting infinite nulls. Why is that so? Is there a way by which I can make the Standard In(Command Line) active after the file being fed into the code is done?
I've tried closing the stream and reopening, it doesn't work. Reset etc also.

Comment: Was the original code edited to take the accepted answer into account. Because that answer does not seem to apply to this code now: the code does not read a file from arg list or any such thing as the answer implies. It would have been better, in that case, to leave the erroneous code in place to make this whole page make more sense.

Comment: @Rondo - no. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1431551/revisions) are the revisions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By executing `"java Read < input.txt"` you've told the operating system that for this process, the piped file *is* standard in. You can't then switch back to the command line from inside the application.

If you want to do that, then pass input.txt as a file name parameter to the application, open/read/close the file yourself from inside the application, then read from standard input to get stuff from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it clarifies

Answer (score 13):

Well, this is typical for reading in a `BufferedReader`. `readLine()` returns `null` when end of stream is hit. Perhaps your infinite loop is the problem ;-)

```
// try / catch ommitted

String x = null;

while( (x = f.readLine()) != null )
{
   System.out.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to terminate your while loop when the line is null, like this:

```
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("IOException reading System.in", e);
        throw e;
    }
    finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way by which I can make the Standard In(Command Line)
>   active after the file being fed into the code is done?

Sorry to bump an old question, but none of the answers so far points out that there *is* a (shell-only) way to pass back to console input after piping in a file.

If you run the command

```
{ cat input.txt & cat; } | java Read
```

then the text from `input.txt` will be passed to `java Read` and you will then be dropped back to console input.

Note that if you then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, you will get the infinite loop of `null`s, unless you modify your program to end the loop when it receives null.