# Read filename from command line argument

Tags: java

I have in my code a hardcoded name for a text file I am reading.

```
String fileName = "test.txt";
```

However I now have to use a command argument like so:

```
 text.java arg1 arg2 arg3 (can be any amount) < test.txt
```

Can anyone help me please?

I have it getting the arguments no problem just not sure on the file. Thank you

I have tried:

```
String x = null;
        try {
            BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            while( (x = f.readLine()) != null )
            {
               System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
               catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
               System.out.println(x);
              }
```

However my application now hangs on readLine, any ideas for me to try please?

Comment: Show us how you get arguments (code).

Comment: This way, you only pass the content of test.txt to the standard input, not the file name.

Comment: @GaborBakos ah that makes more sense, I wrote the code to read it based on the name. Thanks

Comment: @MariuszS I use for (int j = 0; j < ags.length; j++){ //do something} That part is working fine, It was the file I was having issues with :)

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431551/command-line-pipe-input-in-java

Answer (score 2):

That is because the file is not *passed* as an argument, but *piped* as standard input.

If that is the intended use (to pipe the **content** of the file), then you just have to read it from `System.in` (`in` means standard input):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String firstLine = in.readLine();
    // etc.
}
```

If you just wanted to pass the file name, then you have to remove or escape that `<`, because it means "pipe" in shell.

Comment: It seems to hang on the readLine although there is no error, would you have any idea why it would do this?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the file as filename to your program and then open this file and read from it.