# Java: read from unnamed Pipe

Tags: java, pipe

I have a command that gives a list of files (like *find*).

For each of those files i want to do something in Java:

```
find ./files <some restrictions> | java -jar processor.jar
```

how can i read from this unnamed / anonymous Pipe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command Line Pipe Input in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431551/command-line-pipe-input-in-java)

Comment: System.in is your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple really; using a pipe in a shell means that the standard output of the process on the left hand of a pipe is what the standard input of the process on the right hand of the pipe will read.

Therefore, the Java process needs only read stdin, and in Java, this is [`System.in`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in).

---

As to using the `find` command, it's fine, really; but if you use Java 7+ you might consider using a [`FileVisitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) instead and [`Files.walkFileTree()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-).

Comment: but how can i avoid the program try to read from stdin when you run the program without piping?

Comment: Well, you can't use pure Java code to detect whether you read from a pipe; and even if you could I wouldn't recommend it. Why not make your program take options to tell it how it should behave, or recognize arguments (it is customary for instance to use `-` as an argument to tell the program it is to read from stdin)?