# Run exe file using java and giving input to it

Tags: java, exe, processbuilder

I have an exe file, say `Factorial.exe`.

When i run it, it takes `n` and computes `n!`. It is not possible to change the program to pass `n` as a command line argument.

I know how to run this using ProcessBuilder, but I don't know how to give input to it. I think one of the options would be using redirection, so we have :

```
Factorial.exe < input.txt
```

which there is a single number in **input.txt**.

But I can't simply call

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("Factorial.exe < input.txt");
```

or

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("Factorial.exe"," < input.txt");
```

as the input of ProcessBuilder.

---

I found a way to do this, **But i can't call it an answer** its just a way to do it.
I create the input.txt file , with the appropriate input.
I call a batch file using ProcessBuilder with this command :
Factorial.exe < input.txt

this makes it work and i'm gonna use it, but i'm still curious to know is there any better way.

Comment: Something like this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431551/command-line-pipe-input-in-java

Comment: no, in that question, the user is giving the input file to a java program. i want to give input file to an exe file using java

Answer (score 0):

Just add the parameter to the ProcessBuilder-Constructor:

```
new ProcessBuilder("Factorial.exe","5").start();
```

Comment: perhaps is your factorial.exe waiting for some event (e.g. hitting the enter button)?