# java console output become next console input

Tags: java, terminal, pipe

I dont know if it is possible, but i have two simple java class

```
 1. for adding two number (input from terminal)
 2. for doubling and displaying the output from above
```

the output form the first class needs to be the input to the second class

i tried running these few commands but not of them seem to be working:

```
java FirstClass | java SecondClass
java FirstClass > result && java SecondClass < result
```

Is there a method to do what am i trying to? or is it impossible?

Comment: You can create a ``.bat`` file OR create a third class and create object and call method of both class.

Answer (score 0):

```
    BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> adding = (a, b) -> a + b;
    Function<Integer, Integer> doubling = a -> 2 * a;
    System.out.println(adding.andThen(doubling).apply(1, 2));  // -> 6
```

Comment: thanks but i am looking only for a way to be able to run those two classes in which the output of one will be the input of the other!

Answer (score 0):

When you pipe something to a Java program, you have to read from `System.in`. This means you can't access the input as parameters.

See this question for an example: [Command Line Pipe Input in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431551/command-line-pipe-input-in-java)