# How to write a batch file that automatically gives input to a java program that prompts for user input

Tags: java, batch-file

I would like to write a batch file that automatically gives input to a java program that prompts for user input.

My code so far is the following:

```
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin

javac *.java

java myJavaProgram
```

The problem is that when myJavaProgram executes it prompts the user for input, so the batch file waits for me to give input in order to continue execution. I would like to be able to pass the input automatically, using the .bat. Is this possible? Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Updated question to include more context.

In more detail, when `myJavaProgram` is executed from the batch file, it prompts for user input from the console and waits for it. I must give a String. When I write the String, `myJavaProgram` reads it with a Scanner and does something with it (not important what it does). Then it terminates. I want to change the batch code so that I don't need to write the String when it prompts for it. I want to set a variable with my input String in the batch file, and give this as input to `myJavaProgram` "bypassing" the console.

Comment: In general: 1) pass an argument to the program, for example a path to a batch file.  2) Given the existence of the argument, use the argument to get the input.  For example, if the program uses a `Scanner`, create the `Scanner` to read from the file represented by the argument (instead of reading from System.In).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431551/command-line-pipe-input-in-java

Comment: Please don't ever use that syntax, `set path=location`. What it does is remove every piece of string data from the variable values of both the User environment variable, `%Path%`, and the System environment variable `%Path%`. It then temporarily replaces it all with, just `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin`, _(which in my opinion should really be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin;` anyhow)_. It would probably be better to do it like this instead, `If "%Path:~-1%" == ";" (Set "Path=%Path%%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin;") Else Set "Path=%Path%;%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin;"`

Comment: Also, `javac` isn't technically the right command, as that relies upon another variable. `%PATHEXT%`, not having been modified. The value data under `%PATHEXT%` is a listing of executable extensions which are added, in turn, until a file match is found in the current directory, then if not found, each of those within `%Path%`. Why not save that process from happening, and provide the extension yourself. `javac.exe *.java`. Please also take account that you should also therefore use, `java.exe myClass`, for a class file _(no `.class` extension)_, or `java.exe -jar myJar.jar` to run a jar file.

Comment: @Compo Thank you for the answer. You are right but this is not the problem that I am trying to solve here. I will use your suggestions though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Mofi, a more straightforward solution uses the pipe `|` operator, that pipes the output from the first command (echo myString) into the input of the second command (java.exe myJavaProgram).

```
@echo off
If "%Path:~-1%" == ";" (Set "Path=%Path%%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin") Else Set "Path=%Path%;%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin"

javac.exe *.java

echo myString| java.exe myJavaProgram
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. I first redirect the `echo` command output (a string) from the command prompt window to file `temp.txt` using the `>` operator. The file `temp.txt` now contains the string that I want to give as input to `myJavaProgram`. Then I open `temp.txt` and send the output to the command prompt window as input to `myJavaProgram` using the `<` operator. The code is the following:

```
@echo off
If "%Path:~-1%" == ";" (Set "Path=%Path%%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin") Else Set "Path=%Path%;%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin"

javac.exe *.java

echo myString> temp.txt
java.exe myJavaProgram < temp.txt
```